# Avoiding static methods and variables in a Java Class file that handles config.properties

Tags: java, class, oop, static-methods, object-oriented-analysis

I am working on a simple Java Application and I've created a class called Config.java in order to handle the Application properties, thus, avoiding hard-coding.

The Config.java class is not a static class, and I am creating an instance of the Config.java class in another class called Serial.java.

The main method is located in another Class called App.java.  So I have 3 Classes in total:

- App.java
- Serial.java  *(Instance of Config class is located here as a private variable)*
- Config.java

At this stage, all is fine and there are no flaws within the OOP Design.  However, I need to create another class in which I have to call methods from the Config.java class.  What would be the best approach in order to have just **one instance of the Config.java** class:

1. Changing the methods of the Config.java class from public to static?
2. Creating getters and setters for the Config instance which is located in the Serial.java class?

Are there any more options/techniques I can use in order to reach my goal.

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [dependency injection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

---

It sounds like you're instantiating `Config` in `Serial`:

```
class Serial {
    private Config config = new Config();
}
```

Instead of creating it in `Serial`, pass it in:

```
Config config = new Config();
Serial serial = new Serial(config);
```

The `Serial` class would look like:

```
class Serial {
    private Config config;

    public Serial(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}
```

That way you can also pass it to the other object that must call methods from `Config`:

```
OtherObj other = new OtherObj(config);
```

With `OtherObj` defined as:

```
class OtherObj {
    private Config config;

    public OtherObj(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}
```

This well help you avoid static.

Comment: Small addition: to ease dependency injection you can use a D.I. framework (e.g. Dagger)

Comment: Amazing!   First thing in the morning I'm going to implement this and debug to see what exactly is going on.  Thanks Vince Emigh!  You Rock!

Answer (score 0):

Although it depends on details of your domain I see two viable alternatives:

- Add a getConfig method to you App Class (considering that the Config belongs to the App) and using the App instance as a parameter to instantiate object of your new class.
- Go for a singleton, which [has many criticisms](https://www.google.com.mx/webhp?hl=en#hl=en-MX&q=singleton+anti+pattern)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  However, since the main method is located in App.java class its better to leave it untouched, with minimum code as possible. Singleton is a good option too, but in my case, dependency injection beats that approach hands down.

Comment: @MarioGalea yep, Dependency Injection (DI) seems like the way to go. Totally slipped by me, you should post it in your own answer or edit my own. Thanks.