# Get variable from another class within another project

Tags: java, netbeans, client-server, getter-setter

I have 3 project. (and Ignore all Connection to database and Registry to Computer). Project A = API (java library), Project B = Java Class (Server) , Project C = Java Class (Client) .

> in Project A I have 1 java class for entity , lets say (entity.java)

```
private Boolean data;
private String name;    
public void Data_set(Boolean data){
this.data = data;
}
public void Name_set(String name){
this.name = name
}        
public Boolean Data_get() {
return data;
}
public String Name_get() {
return name;
}
```

> in Project A, I have 1 Interface , lets say (interface.java)

```
public void method();
```

> in Project B 1 java class which implements interface.java, lets give it a name (server.java) which import all java & interface class on project A.

```
public void method() {
entity Entity = new entity();
Entity.Data_set(true);
Entity.Name_set("Someone");
}
```

> in Project C 1 java main class, lets give it a name (main.java) which import all java & interface class on project A.

```
server Server = new server();
Server.method();
entity Entity = new entity();
System.out.print("Boolean = "Entity.Data_is();
System.out.print("Name = "Entity.Name_get();
```

> WHAT I WANT.
>   After I run "main.java"
>   It should be below

```
Boolean = true
Name = someone
```

> but it show difference value it show below.

```
Boolean = false
Name = null
```

but if i set entity on "main.java" not in server.java the result there are no problem.

> NOTE for connection database and connection between client-server there are no problem.

Is there any solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if you create an `Entity` in the `Server` class:

```
class Server implements Interface {
    private Entity entity;

    public void method() {
        entity = new Entity();
        entity.setName(...);
        entity.setData(...);
    }
}
```

But rather than print the details of that entity, you create a new one and print the details to that one (which you never assign it any details):

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.method();

        Entity entity = new Entity();
        //print entity
    }
}
```

What you should be doing is grabbing the entity from the server:

```
  class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.method();

        Entity entity = server.getEntity();
        //print entity
    }
}

class Server {
    private Entity entity;

    public void method() {
        entity = new Entity();
        entity.setName(...);
        entity.setData(...);
    }

    public Entity getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }
}
```

As you may have noticed, I used a different style of capitalization than you used. The capitalization style I used is the coding convention people typically use when writing Java. Language have their own styles, it's best to stay consistent with the [language's choice of style](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Comment: Thanks this one is helpme !! :D ..
I just add new getter on the same class as server and get that one on another class in another project.

but somehow I want to know if there is a way to get from another class beside server.java and get it from another class another project.

Comment: @DenniS Check out [my answer on Dependency Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745685/avoiding-static-methods-and-variables-in-a-java-class-file-that-handles-config-p/32745849#32745849) which seems to be answeing a similar question to that and let me know if it helps. If not, I'll update my answer